# Redrawing lines with LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I want to make a small little application where you have 4 lines, each on has the first co-ordinate set somewhere randomly on one of the side of the window and the second co-ordinate will be following the mouse so you get this effect:

[image: img]

You can't see the cursor but the lines meet the cursor in the center.

My problem is that I can't get it keep randomly moving the lines. So every frame or tick or millisecond the lines randomly change position and delete the previous lines. After this I want to change the colour of the lines randomly so it will choose a location and a random position and pretty much give anyone and epileptic fit but I need to figure out the position first.

I've tried doing some of the glClear(GL_...) commands but they don't seem to work. Is there any way to clear the screen entirely and redo the glBegin(GL_LINES) command to position it in another place?

Here's my code:

```
    package tests;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import java.util.Random;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;

public class game {

int wx = 600;
int hy = 400;

int rx = new Random().nextInt(wx);
int ry = new Random().nextInt(hy);

public game() throws LWJGLException {

    int mouseX = Mouse.getX();
    int mouseY = hy-Mouse.getY()-1;

    Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(wx, hy));
    Display.create();
    Display.setTitle("Game");

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, wx, hy, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        lines();

        while(Keyboard.next()) {
            if(Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE) {
                Display.destroy();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        while(Mouse.next()) {
            if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) {
                System.out.println("(" + mouseX + ", " + mouseY + ")");
            }
        }
    }
}

public void lines() {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    int mouseX = Mouse.getX();
    int mouseY = hy-Mouse.getY()-1;

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2i(rx, 0);
        glVertex2i(mouseX, mouseY);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2i(0, ry);
        glVertex2i(mouseX, mouseY);
    glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2i(rx, hy);
        glVertex2i(mouseX, mouseY);
    glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2i(wx, ry);
        glVertex2i(mouseX, mouseY);
    glEnd();
        glLineWidth(5);
        glColor3f(1f, 0f, 0f);

    Display.update();
    Display.sync(500);

}


public static void main(String[] args) throws LWJGLException {
    new game();
    }
}
```

Comment: "but they don't seem to work" What do you mean by this? What doesn't work about them?

Comment: I mean they don't do what I want them to do. Ie, get rid of the current lines and recreate new ones with lines().

Comment: So what does your application look like then? It'd be very useful for us to know.

Comment: It's in the question but here http://i.stack.imgur.com/cm1tT.png

Comment: Oh never mind, someone was kind enough to edit it into the question. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your `rx`/`ry` calculation inside `lines()`:

```
public void lines() 
{
    int rx = new Random().nextInt(wx);
    int ry = new Random().nextInt(hy);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    int mouseX = Mouse.getX();
    int mouseY = hy-Mouse.getY()-1;

    glLineWidth(5);
    glColor3f(1f, 0f, 0f);

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2i(rx, 0);
        glVertex2i(mouseX, mouseY);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2i(0, ry);
        glVertex2i(mouseX, mouseY);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2i(rx, hy);
        glVertex2i(mouseX, mouseY);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2i(wx, ry);
        glVertex2i(mouseX, mouseY);
    glEnd();

    Display.update();
    Display.sync(500);
}
```

Comment: Oh wow that worked!!! Thanks so much!!!
I don't want to blindly add it in, so could explain why it works please? Thanks.

Comment: Before you got two random numbers when `game` was instantiated and never changed them.  This way you get two new random numbers each time you draw.